# Two qubit Pauli expectation value of $\underset{U}{\mathbb{E}}[U^{\otimes 2} (P_1 \otimes P_2)^{\otimes 2} U^{*\otimes 2}]$

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, random-quantum-circuit, haar-distribution

I want to find a value for the expression:

$$\underset{U}{\mathbb{E}}[U^{\otimes 2} (P_1 \otimes P_2)^{\otimes 2} U^{*\otimes 2}],$$

where $U$ is a two-qubit unitary operator chosen Haar randomly, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two single qubit Pauli operators, and the expectation is taken over choices of $U$.

---

When both Paulis are identity, the expression is trivially $1$. However, I wasn't entirely sure of the other cases.

Comment: is the second unitary supposed to be $U^{\dagger}$ instead of $U^*$?

Comment: Yes, thats’s right!

Comment: When you say that the expectation is equal to $1$, do you mean the identity? Or else, isn't the inside of the expectation a matrix?

Comment: I mean the identity.

Comment: Do you know already the answer to the simpler problem where you do not have $^{\otimes 2}$ everywhere? In general, of course, one does not know $E(X^2)$ from $E(X)$ and it may be even harder to find $E(X^{\otimes 2})$ from $E(X)$

Comment: My thinking is to expand each Pauli as $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|-|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|$ such that you get an expression in terms of sums of averages for a bunch of different states in the convex combination formed by the Pauli operators (like $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|\otimes |\phi\rangle\langle \phi|\otimes\cdots$). If you can do the average for arbitrary pure states then you'd be golden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove a slightly more general statement, which works for any Hermitian "sandwiched" matrix $P$ in any dimension $d$... but only for $t=2$ in the number of copies :'(

Let us call $V$ this expectation, and let $W$ be a unitary matrix. We have:
$$\begin{align*}
W^{\otimes2}V &= \int_U\left(WUPU^\dagger\right)^{\otimes 2}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(U)\\
&= \int_U\left(UPU^\dagger W\right)^{\otimes 2}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(UW)\\
&= \int_U\left(UPU^\dagger W\right)^{\otimes 2}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(U)\\
&= VW^{\otimes 2}.
\end{align*}$$
Thus, $V$ commutes with every $W^{\otimes 2}$ for $W\in \mathcal{U}(d)$.

We now want to use Schur's Lemma. We know that the symmetric subspace $\vee^2\mathbb{C}^d$ and the antisymmetric one are both irreducible representations of the group action $W\mapsto W^{\otimes 2}$. Furthermore, the former has dimension $\binom{d+1}{2}$ and the latter $\binom{d}{2}$, which conveniently sums up to $d^2$. Thus, we know that $V$ can be written as:
$$V=\lambda_1P_{\text{sym}}+\lambda_2P_{\text{antisym}}$$
where $P_{\text{sym}}$ and $P_{\text{antisym}}$ are the respective projectors onto these subspaces.

We can evaluate $\lambda_1$ by computing:
$$\lambda_1=\langle00|V|00\rangle=\int_U(\langle0|UPU^\dagger|0\rangle)^2\,\mathrm{d}\mu(U).$$
Since $P$ is Hermitian, $\langle0|UPU^\dagger|0\rangle$ is real. Thus, we can write:
$$\lambda_1=\int_U|\langle0|UPU^\dagger|0\rangle|^2\,\mathrm{d}\mu(U)$$
This is a [known quantity](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/33129/10454) and we have:
$$\lambda_1=\frac{\mathrm{tr}^2(P)+d}{(d+1)d}$$
Note also that we have, once again using the fact that $P$ is Hermitian:
$$\mathrm{tr}(V)=\lambda_1\binom{d+1}{2}+\lambda_2\binom{d}{2}=\mathrm{tr}^2(P).$$
Which gives us:
$$\lambda_2=\frac{\mathrm{tr}^2(P)-d}{d(d-1)}.$$
If $P$ is a Pauli matrix, it simplifies a lot, since the identity is the only one with a non-nil trace. For $P=I$, we find $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$, which gives us $$V=P_{\text{sym}}+P_{\text{anti}}=I,$$ and for any other Pauli matrix this gives us $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{d+1}$ and $\lambda_2=-\frac{1}{d-1}$, which gives us $$V=\frac{1}{d+1}P_{\text{sym}}-\frac{1}{d-1}P_{\text{anti}}.$$